# How can I give access to a external user to my Azure database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I've recently created a App Service + SQL in my Azure account and I want to give access to some external user, maybe using SQL authentication with username and password. I know I must allow this user IP, but I cannot find where I can create credentials or a new user for him.

I've tried creating a new login and user using SQL statements but I can't access master database.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to grant users access to Master.  Instead connect to the target database as an administrator and simply add the user using [CREATE USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql)

```
CREATE USER SomeUserName WITH PASSWORD = 'somestrongpassword123'
```

See generally [Controlling and granting database access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins)